# How to plot top observations in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

this is probably pretty straightforward but new to R and have not been able to find a question quite like this one. I want to plot the top ten observations in my data set and have tried slice_max() but I end up plotting the whole data set. Please see below for what I have so far. Any help would be much appreciated!

Summary of data set that I am trying to plot
[image: Summary of data set that I a trying to plot]

Here's my script for when I try to plot the above data set and I get the whole data set instead of the top ten.

```r
Non_DFW_Orig_Counties %>%
  slice_max(Non_DFW_Orig_Counties$tax_returns_by_county, n = 10) %>%
  ggplot(data = Non_DFW_Orig_Counties, mapping = aes(x = Orig_County, y = tax_returns_by_county, fill = Dest_County)) +
  geom_col()
```

Thank you to teunbrand for the stackoverflow etiquette. Is there a page where all stackoverflow etiquette is populated?

Comment: You're populating the `data` argument of the `ggplot()` function with the unmodified data. Does removing `data = Non_DFW_Orig_Counties, ` help? Also please don't share data as an image for the reasons mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827). The preferred way for sharing R data is copy-pasting the output of `dput(example_data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data set is ordered, you can do

```
Non_DFW_Orig_Counties[1:10,]  %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Orig_County, y = tax_returns_by_county, fill = Dest_County)) +
  geom_col()
```

This will select the first ten rows of the data set and all columns. You also do not need the data argument in `ggplot` because you are using the pipe

Comment: That's it! Thanks!